# Submit button gives value as Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a form, and I am trying to get value of submit button when I click on it.

I have below code..

HTML:`

```
                    <div>
                        <input id="Submit_id" type="submit" value="Insert" />
                    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $("#Submit_id").click(function () {

            var submitval = $("#submit_id").html();
  alert (submitval);
});
```

This gives me value undefined. Could you please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: You want .val() not .html() - $(this).val() within the callback

Comment: I have also tried .val() and .content().

Comment: `submit_id` vs `Submit_id`. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Hi saminOz, I was just commenting on it and i saw your comment.

I will try using $(this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jquery selector needs to be capitalized to match your input id.  Also, you want to get the `prop('value')` and not `.html()`

```
<div>
    <input id="Submit_id" type="submit" value="Insert" />
</div>


$("#Submit_id").click(function () {
    var submitval = $("#Submit_id").prop('value');
    //var submitval = $(this).val(); //also works as @SaminOz suggested
    alert (submitval);
});
```

Edit to add: You can see it working at this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jg1k2ot4/1/